# How to Prevent debuggers like HTTP Debugger Pro from viewing my POST Request in a C# WPF app

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, post, http-post

How would I prevent a apps like HTTP Debugger from viewing all data being posted via a C# WPF application.

Comment: The short answer: there is no way.

What is the higher-level problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: You can't forbid a client from viewing the HTTP request. Even the browser's dev-tools have tools that show you the http traffic, probably even better than the software you mentioned. if you mean you want to hide the data, you can just encrypt them but they will still be able to see the name of each field and also that's the only job of HTTPS to encrypt data so outsiders can't access them. I do not understand your logic. Is there a point in preventing the person who send the data from the browser, to view the data in a packet viewing tool?

Comment: If the protection offered by https is insufficient you could perhaps do custom serialisation and encrypt your data. Maybe http isn't suitable for your app.